# CakePHP Using "Group By" in Virtual Field Not Working

Tags: mysql, cakephp, group-by, cakephp-2.2

I have the following virtual field on my Page model

```
function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    $this->virtualFields['fans'] = 'SELECT COUNT(Favorite.id) FROM favorites AS Favorite WHERE Favorite.page_id = Page.id AND Favorite.status = 0';
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}
```

This works as expected and displays the number of users who have added the page to their favorites. The issue is that, during development, some rows have duplicate user_id to page_id pairs so it returns the incorrect number or unique users. I tried adding a group by clause like so

```
$this->virtualFields['fans'] = 'SELECT COUNT(Favorite.id) FROM favorites AS Favorite WHERE Favorite.page_id = Page.id AND Favorite.status = 0 GROUP BY Favorite.user_id';
```

But it does not work. I tried debugging the issue but I receive the error message "allowed memory size exhausted". I also tried using `SELECT COUNT('Favorite.user_id')` and `SELECT DISTINCT('Favorite.user_id')` neither of which worked either. I believe DISTINCT is further away from the answer as that would return an array (I believe?)

Is this a known CakePHP issue? Am I implementing the group by wrong? Is there another solution to do this other than afterfind?

Comment: Page.id just corresponds to whatever ID the current row in the pages table is pulling information for. For example, if on the pages index.ctp I display a list of all pages in a table and show the title and corresponding number of fans (using the first virtual field method I mentioned above), it displays the count of fans for that page (except not distinct number of fans). Just now I tested changing "WHERE Favorite.page_id = Page.id" to "WHERE Favorite.page_id = 1" and I still receive the same issue of too much memory. So I don't think Page.id not explicitly being set is the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Favorite.user_id)
```

like that :

```
 $this->virtualFields['fans'] = 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM favorites  WHERE  status = 0';
```

Comment: Thank you!! For some reason I was soooooooooo certain that was not going to work since I tried DISTINCT on its own. But it did. Lesson learned: exhaust all options even if you think it won't work because it might be "that one" that just so happen that it does.